# Smart Contract in NEAR

Tags: nearprotocol

I am working on (a  smart contract in NEAR ) "nft collection where only admin can mint tokens"  This is causing an error  ExecutionError: "Smart contract panicked: Method mint_nft doesn't accept deposit"   },   can anyone help me in this regard. #nearprotocol

help me in this regard

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During call the function you seem to put the `--deposit` flag the error says that that this function does not expect that(attached near). If you want to accept payment you have to decorate the function with the `#[payable]` macro.